# What is I/O Scaling Problem in nodeJS Performance?

Tags: node.js

Can you please explain what is the I/O Scaling Problem in Node.js Performance?
I am reading the book ["Basarat Ali Syed - Beginning Node.js-Apress"](https://www.apress.com/br/book/9781484201886) but the explanation is not enough to I/O Scaling.

Comment: What book are you reading?  And, what problem are you talking about?  "I/O Scaling Problem" is not a well-understood term for node.js.  We could make wild guesses what it might be, but your question ought to really say what it is that you're asking for.

Comment: I am reading the "Basarat Ali Syed - Begining Node.js-Apress" book. I just want to know what is I/O scaling Problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A server typically has a mix of computational things to do and I/O things to do (getting data from somewhere like a database or a disk or another server).  In today's modern servers with pretty fast multi-core processors, it is more common for a given server request to be limited by I/O than by CPU.

So, if you're going to scale a server to be able to handle lots of requests and to handle them with good performance, you have to find a way to be able to most efficiently handle lots of I/O requests because that's probably what your server is limited by.  This would be the "I/O scaling problem".  How to scale your server and code architecture to handle lots of I/O requests very efficiently.

It so happens that the node.js single-threaded architecture with asynchronous I/O is very efficient at doing lots of I/O and can be more efficient than other server architectures that use multiple threads and blocking I/O calls.

If you go to your Table of Contents in that book, you will see the following:

```
Understanding Node.js Performance 
    The I/O Scaling Problem
    Traditional Web Servers Using a Process Per Request
    Traditional Web Servers Using a Thread Pool
    The Nginx way
    Node.js Performance Secret
```

I don't have the book myself, but I would presume that "The I/O Scaling Problem" section of the book describes it for you.  And, then you can read about the node.js performance secret for how it handles this.  The servers that use a process or a thread per request take more system resources to have lots of requests in flight at the same time (which is one key to handle lots of requests).  The node.js non-blocking I/O model, on the other hand, is very efficient at handling lots and lots of in-flight requests.